# azure Pipeline help: Run az cli stmt and evaluate the response as part of an IF block

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I am creating an azure yaml pipeline and within an AzureClI@2 task I want to run the cli stmt 'az group exists...' with a local variable as the name and evaluate the statement's response, something like this:

```
 if ( az group exists -n $(dev-resource-group) = false)
 then
  # do something super cool here.
 elseif
  # do something less cool else.
 fi
```

There are lots of examples for variables but I'm unable to get this to work executing a cli stmt. I'm thinking that this needs to be runtime, so `${{ }}` will probably be required. Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: You have to write a shell script. PowerShell or cmd for Windows, Bash for Linux. If you're not familiar with shell scripting, start by researching conditionals in your shell scripting language of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with **@Daniel Mann** you need to use Script Type as Shell, Refer below:-

[image]

I tried the below code with if and else block in AzureCLI@2 to check if my resource group exist and it worked successfully like below:-

**By setting the $y to true:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subscripption'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      x="rgname"
      y=$(az group exists --name $x --output json)
      
      if [ "$y" = "true" ]; then
          echo "Hello Rithwik Resource group exist"
      else
          echo "Hello Rithwik Resource group does not exist"
      fi
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**By setting the $y to false:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subscription'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      x="rgname2"
      y=$(az group exists --name $x --output json)
      
      if [ "$y" = "false" ]; then
          echo "Hello Rithwik Resource group exist"
      else
          echo "Hello Rithwik Resource group does not exist"
      fi
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using Powershell, though I'd prefer to use @RithwikBojja and his bash example. Hope this helps another if powershell is your preferred language.  Tab/spacing might need to be adjusted if you cut and paste the yaml.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:  
  - name: rgName
    value: test-resource-group
    
  - name: loc
    value: eastus

  - name: serviceConnection
    value: my-test-sp-conn-all

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
          azurePowershellVersion: latestVersion
          pwsh: true
          scriptType: inlineScript      
          inline: |
            Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $(rgName) -Location $(loc) -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            
            if ($notPresent)
            {
              echo "##[debug]Starting creation of $(rgName)"
              New-AzResourceGroup -Name $(rgName) -Location $(loc) 
              echo "##[debug]Created resource group"    
            }
             else
             {
               echo "##[debug]Resource group '$(rgName)' already exists."   
             }
```